# Two IP for each interface?

Tags: networking, server

I have edited my interfaces file in order to set a static IP for my network interface card.

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Since then, everytime i run the command **hostname -I**, I see two different IP: a random IP and the one I setted (192.168.1.100).
Why?

---

This is the output I get:

```
192.168.1.100 192.168.1.102
```

while this is the output I would expect:

```
192.168.1.100
```

Comment: Can you add the exact output you are getting to your question ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: The network address should be `network 192.168.1.0`

Comment: You also don't need the 'network' field, I don't think...

Answer (score 0):

Please try your interfaces file like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.100
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

And check:

```
hostname -I
```

Since the definition of -I in `man hostname` says:

> Display  all  network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on  all  network  interfaces.  The
>                 loopback  interface  and  IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted.
>                 Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend on name resolution.  Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

...then I suspect that if ethernet is or previously was connected, both of the configured IP address will be retained and shown whether currently connected or not.

Comment: I edited the interface file in the way you wrote, but nothing changed: **hostname -i** returns **127.0.1.1**, while **hostname -I** returns **192.168.1.100 192.168.1.103**.

Comment: By chance, do you have both wireless and ethernet connected and both with IP addresses at the same time? `ifconfig`.

Comment: Not on that machine, no.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: So you think that the second IP address is a sort of temporary address, assigned to the nic before the static IP defined in the config file?

Comment: Probably; or either a former address claimed by the ethernet. Are you using Network Manager? Is there more than one entry in /var/lib/NetworkManager/***.lease?

Comment: I checked, and I am able to connect using both the IP, so it isn't a temporary address. No I don't use Network Manager.